# Mongoose TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '_id' in

Tags: node.js, backbone.js

I've a rails developer trying my hand at backbone and using the Backbone.js application book - my first Backbone / Node / Mongo app so be gentle.

I've poured over the similar questions and have been stuck for 12 hours now so I think it's time to throw in the towel.  error is above and below

```
[TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '_id' in YES PLEASE]
```

I'm trying to save a Book to the library, here is my schema.

```
var Keywords = new mongoose.Schema({
    keyword: String
});

var Book = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    author: String,
    releaseDate: Date,
    keywords: [ Keywords ]
});
```

When I do a simple Ajax post, the Keywords get displayed and saved, but when I try to add them from the view, they fail.  Here is the library.js view.

```
var app = app || {};

app.LibraryView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: "#books",

  events: {
    'click #add': "addBook"
  },

  initialize: function() {
    this.collection = new app.Library();
    this.collection.fetch({reset: true});
    this.render();

    this.listenTo(this.collection, 'add', this.renderBook );
    this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.render)
  },

  render: function() {
    this.collection.each(function(item) {
      this.renderBook(item);
    }, this);
  },

  renderBook: function(item) {
    var bookView = new app.BookView({
      model: item
    });
    this.$el.append(bookView.render().el );
  },

  addBook: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = {};

    $('#addBook div').children('input').each(function( i,el ) {
      if( $( el ).val() != '' )
      {
        if( el.id ==="kewords" ) {
          _.each( $(el).val().split(' '), function( keyword ){
            formData[ el.id ].push({ 'keyword': keyword });
          });
        } else if ( el.id ==='releaseDate' ){
          formData[ el.id ] = $("#releaseDate").datepicker('getDate').getTime();
        } else {
          formData[ el.id ] = $( el ).val();
        }
      }
      $( el ).val('')
    });

    this.collection.create( formData );
  }
});
```

Any help would be most welcome.  Also, what are best practices for debugging javascript? Going into the console and drilling down? Is there a better debugger library to use with node?

Thanks

Comment: Typo: Missing `y` of `keywords` in `if( el.id ==="kewords" )`. Also, note that you won't be able to `.push()` onto an Array that hasn't yet been created -- `var formData = { keywords: [] };`

Comment: christ it's always the little things

Comment: With the typo, the `formData` likely contained `keywords: "YES PLEASE"` rather than `keywords: [ { keyword: "YES" }, { keyword: "PLEASE" } ]`. And, expecting an array/object for `keywords`, Mongoose tried to check for an `_id` property with [the `in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in), which doesn't work on non-objects, like string primitives. To check this, you can either set a breakpoint on `this.collection.create( formData );` to pause execution or place a `console.dir(formData);` before it to log it to the Console.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your post data JSON objects properties is wrong. I faced same problem after my correction, the issue is gone.

**Issue state:**

```
  {"userId": "58821f9b1b059b515a53d44b","dashboard":"mobile_dashboard"}
```

**After correction:**

```
{"userId": "58821f9b1b059b515a53d44b","dashboard":{"title":"mobile_dashboard","viewData":{"className":"BuilderDroppableZone"}}}
```